# W/Parcel ( 8822): Expecting binder but got null! on android studio

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Im getting this error `W/Parcel  ( 8822): Expecting binder but got null!` when running the below code.

Code:

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      XylophoneApp(),
    );

class XylophoneApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: OutlinedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                final player = AudioPlayer(); // Audio player
                player.play(
                    UrlSource('note1.wav')); // will immediately start playing
                await player.play(AssetSource('asset/note1.wav'));
              },
              child: Text('Click Me'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The warning

```
W/Parcel ( 8822): Expecting binder but got null!
```

Here's the console:
[image: console]

pubspec.yaml
[image: pubspec.yaml]

flutter doctor:
[image: flutter doctor]

assets folder:

[image: assets folder]

This is what I get when I click the button on onClick() with the warning

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:59516/Nb3xIBlDGmY=/ws
Syncing files to device sdk gphone x86 64...
I/lophone_flutter(11340): Compiler allocated 4533KB to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()
W/Parcel  (11340): Expecting binder but got null!
E/flutter (11340): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: "assets/asset/note1.wav".
E/flutter (11340): The asset does not exist or has empty data.
E/flutter (11340): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:328:9)
E/flutter (11340): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11340): #1      AudioCache.fetchToMemory (package:audioplayers/src/audio_cache.dart:88:22)
E/flutter (11340): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11340): #2      AudioCache.load (package:audioplayers/src/audio_cache.dart:114:31)
E/flutter (11340): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11340): #3      AudioPlayer.setSourceAsset (package:audioplayers/src/audioplayer.dart:337:17)
E/flutter (11340): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11340): #4      AudioPlayer.setSource (package:audioplayers/src/audioplayer.dart:284:5)
E/flutter (11340): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11340): #5      AudioPlayer.play (package:audioplayers/src/audioplayer.dart:182:5)
E/flutter (11340): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11340): #6      XylophoneApp.build.<anonymous closure> (package:xylophone_flutter/main.dart:20:17)
E/flutter (11340): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11340): 
D/EGL_emulation(11340): app_time_stats: avg=6796.08ms min=3.35ms max=13588.81ms count=2
V/MediaPlayer(11340): resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
V/MediaPlayer(11340): cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null
E/flutter (11340): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(AndroidAudioError, note1.wav: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory), java.io.FileNotFoundException: note1.wav: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
E/flutter (11340):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:574)
E/flutter (11340):  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:160)
E/flutter (11340):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1209)
E/flutter (11340):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1187)
E/flutter (11340):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1152)
E/flutter (11340):  at xyz.luan.audioplayers.source.UrlSource.setForMediaPlayer(UrlSource.kt:16)
E/flutter (11340):  at xyz.luan.audioplayers.player.MediaPlayerPlayer.setSource(MediaPlayerPlayer.kt:53)
E/flutter (11340):  at xyz.luan.audioplayers.player.WrappedPlayer.setSource(WrappedPlayer.kt:29)
E/flutter (11340):  at xyz.luan.audioplayers.AudioplayersPlugin.methodHandler(AudioplayersPlugin.kt:126)
E/flutter (11340):  at xyz.luan.audioplayers.AudioplayersPlugin.access$methodHandler(AudioplayersPlugin.kt:29)
E/flutter (11340):  at xyz.luan.audioplayers.AudioplayersPlugin$onAttachedToEngine$1$1.invoke(AudioplayersPlugin.kt:50)
E/flutter (11340):  at xyz.luan.audioplayers.AudioplayersPlugin$onAttachedToEngine$1$1.invoke(AudioplayersPlugin.kt:50)
E/flutter (11340):  at xyz.luan.audioplayers.AudioplayersPlugin$safeCall$1.invokeSuspend(AudioplayersPlugin.kt:75)
E/flutter (11340):  at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
E/flutter (11340):  at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
E/flutter (11340):  at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:42)
E/flutter (11340):  at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
E/flutter (11340):  at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
E/flutter (11340):  at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
E/flutter (11340):  at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
E/flutter (11340):  at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
E/flutter (11340): Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
E/flutter (11340):  at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
E/flutter (11340):  at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:563)
E/flutter (11340):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:274)
E/flutter (11340):  at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:563)
E/flutter (11340):  at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7758)
E/flutter (11340):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:560)
E/flutter (11340):  ... 20 more
E/flutter (11340): , null)
E/flutter (11340): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:652:7)
E/flutter (11340): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:310:18)
E/flutter (11340): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11340): #2      AudioPlayer._completePrepared (package:audioplayers/src/audioplayer.dart:301:5)
E/flutter (11340): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11340): #3      AudioPlayer.setSourceUrl (package:audioplayers/src/audioplayer.dart:313:5)
E/flutter (11340): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11340): #4      AudioPlayer.setSource (package:audioplayers/src/audioplayer.dart:284:5)
E/flutter (11340): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11340): #5      AudioPlayer.play (package:audioplayers/src/audioplayer.dart:182:5)
E/flutter (11340): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11340):
```

I tried:
flutter clean
flutter doctor
clean cache
updated SDK, IDE and flutter
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); on main() <-- This i tried didnt work im not sure if this works

And due to the above errors i cant get my output on onClick().

Feel free to ask any doubts :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This it the answer for the above issue.

```
child: OutlinedButton(
    onPressed: () async {
        final player = AudioPlayer(); // Audio player
        player.play(
            UrlSource('note1.wav')); // will immediately start playing
            await player.play(AssetSource('note1.wav'));
    },
    child: Text('Click Me'),
),
```

Comment: For those like me who don't see the difference: the solution removes the "asset/" prefix from the path of the .wav file argument to `AssetSource`. (I'd prefer to edit the answer but the edit queue is full.)